# Formula(s) that reference this field are no longer valid: Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,031 characters)

Tags: formula

I am using a formula field then i encountered this error. I have tried using case function but the compile size is still above max. I have also tried passing the value to another formula field but the compile size just goes higher. I cannot use field update/trigger because I am on a professional edition org. Is there any way that i can lower the compile size?

This is my error.

> Formula(s) that reference this field are no longer valid: Compiled
>   formula is too big to execute (5,031 characters). Maximum size is
>   5,000 characters (Related field: Formula)

This is the code for formula field

```
IF( TEXT(Sales_Category__c) = 'Exempt Sales', 0, 

IF(Commission_No__c = 0,  
              Commission_1__c * 0.10, 
              Commission_2__c *0.10)

)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of fields are those 4 fields?  If they're formula fields, the size of those formulas is added to this formula.

Comment: Sales_Category__c is picklist, Commission_No__c  is currency, Commission_1__c  andCommission_1__c    is formula.

Comment: You can normally solve this with workflow rules but you're on professional edition.  Can you post the formulas for `Commission_1__c` and `Commission_2__c`? You'll need to reduce the size of them to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already said that Commission_1__c and Commission_2__c are formula fields, try slimming those two down. Salesforce calculates all the referenced formula fields' compiled size to total any formula field's compile size.

Answer (score -2):

Can you split your formula field into two formula field?Something like this:

First formula field contains formula:

```
IF(Commission_No__c = 0,  
              Commission_1__c * 0.10, 
              Commission_2__c *0.10)
```

Second formula field contains formula that also read from first formula field :

```
IF( TEXT(Sales_Category__c) = 'Exempt Sales', 0, 

First_custom_Field

)
```

Comment: This won't work because Salesforce is smart enough to add the two compile sizes together

Comment: I have tried it but the compile size is greater than having it in just one formula field.